# variable not define is vba formula

Tags: excel, vba, variables

my variable uuid does not pick up in the the number.

in the excel it still shows `=COUNTIF(AB11:AL11,uuid)` but it should be 
`=COUNTIF(AB11:AL11,1234567)`

```
uuid = Worksheets("Search").Cells(2, 4)
Range("AV2:AV" & lastrows).Formula = "=COUNTIF(AB2:AL2,uuid)"
```

Comment: `"=COUNTIF(AB2:AL2," & uuid & ")"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a variable inside a text string. You need to concatenate the text with the variable.

In your case, the text string is a formula.  Split that formula text string where the variable needs to go and use the ampersand & sign to put the pieces together.

```
Range("AV2:AV" & lastrows).Formula = "=COUNTIF(AB2:AL2," & uuid & ")"
```